# Java Backpropagation Algorithm is very slow

Tags: java, algorithm, backpropagation

I have a big problem. I try to create a neural network and want to train it with a backpropagation algorithm. I found this tutorial here http://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/ and tried to recreate it in Java. And when I use the training data he uses, I get the same results as him. 
Without backpropagation my TotalError is nearly the same as his. And when I use the back backpropagation 10 000 time like him, than I get the nearly the same error. But he uses 2 Input Neurons, 2 Hidden Neurons and 2 Outputs but I'd like to use this neural network for OCR, so I need definitely more Neurons. But if I use for example 49 Input Neurons, 49 Hidden Neurons and 2 Output Neurons, It takes very long to change the weights to get a small error. (I believe it takes forever.....). I have a learningRate of 0.5. In the constructor of my network, I generate the neurons and give them the same training data like the one in the tutorial and for testing it with more neurons, I gave them random weights, inputs and targets. So can't I use this for many Neurons, does it takes just very long or is something wrong with my code ? Shall I increase the learning rate, the bias or the start weight?
Hopefully you can help me.

```
package de.Marcel.NeuralNetwork;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Network {
    private ArrayList<Neuron> inputUnit, hiddenUnit, outputUnit;

    private double[] inHiWeigth, hiOutWeigth;
    private double hiddenBias, outputBias;

    private double learningRate;

    public Network(double learningRate) {
        this.inputUnit = new ArrayList<Neuron>();
        this.hiddenUnit = new ArrayList<Neuron>();
        this.outputUnit = new ArrayList<Neuron>();

        this.learningRate = learningRate;

        generateNeurons(2,2,2);

        calculateTotalNetInputForHiddenUnit();
        calculateTotalNetInputForOutputUnit();
    }

    public double calcuteLateTotalError () {
        double e = 0;
        for(Neuron n : outputUnit) {
            e += 0.5 * Math.pow(Math.max(n.getTarget(), n.getOutput()) - Math.min(n.getTarget(), n.getOutput()), 2.0);
        }

        return e;
    }

    private void generateNeurons(int input, int hidden, int output) {
        // generate inputNeurons
        for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
            Neuron neuron = new Neuron();

            // for testing give each neuron an input
            if(i == 0) {
                neuron.setInput(0.05d);
            } else if(i == 1) {
                neuron.setOutput(0.10d);
            }

            inputUnit.add(neuron);
        }

        // generate hiddenNeurons
        for (int i = 0; i < hidden; i++) {
            Neuron neuron = new Neuron();

            hiddenUnit.add(neuron);
        }

        // generate outputNeurons
        for (int i = 0; i < output; i++) {
            Neuron neuron = new Neuron();

            if(i == 0) {
                neuron.setTarget(0.01d);
            } else if(i == 1) {
                neuron.setTarget(0.99d);
            }

            outputUnit.add(neuron);
        }

        // generate Bias
        hiddenBias = 0.35;
        outputBias = 0.6;

        // generate connections
        double startWeigth = 0.15;
        // generate inHiWeigths
        inHiWeigth = new double[inputUnit.size() * hiddenUnit.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < inputUnit.size() * hiddenUnit.size(); i += hiddenUnit.size()) {
            for (int x = 0; x < hiddenUnit.size(); x++) {
                int z = i + x;
                inHiWeigth[z] = round(startWeigth, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

                startWeigth += 0.05;
            }
        }

        // generate hiOutWeigths
        hiOutWeigth = new double[hiddenUnit.size() * outputUnit.size()];
        startWeigth += 0.05;
        for (int i = 0; i < hiddenUnit.size() * outputUnit.size(); i += outputUnit.size()) {
            for (int x = 0; x < outputUnit.size(); x++) {
                int z = i + x;
                hiOutWeigth[z] = round(startWeigth, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);

                startWeigth += 0.05;
            }
        }
    }

    private double round(double unrounded, int precision, int roundingMode)
    {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(unrounded);
        BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(precision, roundingMode);
        return rounded.doubleValue();
    }

    private void calculateTotalNetInputForHiddenUnit() {
        // calculate totalnetinput for each hidden neuron
        for (int s = 0; s < hiddenUnit.size(); s++) {
            double net = 0;
            int x = (inHiWeigth.length / inputUnit.size());

            // calculate toAdd
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                int v = i + s * x;
                double weigth = inHiWeigth[v];
                double toAdd = weigth * inputUnit.get(i).getInput();
                net += toAdd;
            }

            // add bias
            net += hiddenBias * 1;
            net = net *-1;
            double output =  (1.0 / (1.0 + (double)Math.exp(net)));
            hiddenUnit.get(s).setOutput(output);
        }
    }

    private void calculateTotalNetInputForOutputUnit() {
        // calculate totalnetinput for each hidden neuron
        for (int s = 0; s < outputUnit.size(); s++) {
            double net = 0;
            int x = (hiOutWeigth.length / hiddenUnit.size());

            // calculate toAdd
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                int v = i + s * x;
                double weigth = hiOutWeigth[v];
                double outputOfH = hiddenUnit.get(s).getOutput();
                double toAdd = weigth * outputOfH;
                net += toAdd;
            }

            // add bias
            net += outputBias * 1;
            net = net *-1;
            double output = (double) (1.0 / (1.0 + Math.exp(net)));
            outputUnit.get(s).setOutput(output);
        }
    }

    private void backPropagate() {
        // calculate ouputNeuron weigthChanges
        double[] oldWeigthsHiOut = hiOutWeigth;
        double[] newWeights = new double[hiOutWeigth.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < hiddenUnit.size(); i += 1) {
            double together = 0;
            double[] newOuts = new double[hiddenUnit.size()];
            for (int x = 0; x < outputUnit.size(); x++) {
                int z = x * hiddenUnit.size() + i;
                double weigth = oldWeigthsHiOut[z];
                double target = outputUnit.get(x).getTarget();
                double output = outputUnit.get(x).getOutput();

                double totalErrorChangeRespectOutput = -(target - output);
                double partialDerivativeLogisticFunction = output * (1 - output);
                double totalNetInputChangeWithRespect = hiddenUnit.get(x).getOutput();
                double puttedAllTogether = totalErrorChangeRespectOutput * partialDerivativeLogisticFunction
                        * totalNetInputChangeWithRespect;
                double weigthChange = weigth - learningRate * puttedAllTogether;

                // set new weigth
                newWeights[z] = weigthChange;
                together += (totalErrorChangeRespectOutput * partialDerivativeLogisticFunction * weigth);
                double out = hiddenUnit.get(x).getOutput();
                newOuts[x] = out * (1.0 - out);
            }
            for (int t = 0; t < newOuts.length; t++) {
                inHiWeigth[t + i] = (double) (inHiWeigth[t + i] - learningRate * (newOuts[t] * together * inputUnit.get(t).getInput()));
            }
            hiOutWeigth = newWeights;
        }
    }
}
```

And my Neuron Class:

```
package de.Marcel.NeuralNetwork;

public class Neuron {
    private double input, output;
    private double target;

    public Neuron () {

    }

    public void setTarget(double target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public void setInput (double input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public void setOutput(double output) {
        this.output = output;
    }

    public double getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public double getOutput() {
        return output;
    }

    public double getTarget() {
        return target;
    }
}
```

Comment: many neurons takes a long time

Comment: your code seems to be fine. At most you can substitute every call to the .size() method with a pre-loaded variable in order to avoid thousands and thousands of calls. Then think that deep neural networks can take days to be trained. Google has clusters of HPC doing this all days, all day long

Comment: @FMiscia But I don't have so many neurons and if I increase the neurons and train for example 900000 times the error doesn't change. :)s

Comment: The error converges over time towards a single value. If the error is not changing, either you have reached convergence every time, or you have an error in your code. Try training it with 10, 100, 1000 etc times and see how much the error changes between each step.

Comment: Having two layers your complexity goes like n^n, so try step by step to increase you training number.

Answer (score 2):

Think about it: you have 10,000 propagations through 49->49->2 neurons. Between the input layer and the hidden layer, you have 49 * 49 links to propagate through, so parts of your code are being executed about 24 million times (10,000 * 49 * 49). That is going to take time. You could try 100 propogations, and see how long it takes, just to give you an idea.

There are a few things that can be done to increase performance, like using a plain array instead of an ArrayList, but this is a better topic for the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. Also, don't expect this to give drastic improvements.

Answer (score 1):

Your back propagation code has complexity of O(h*o + h^2) * 10000, where h is the number of hidden neurons and o is the number of output neurons. Here's why.

You have a loop that executes for all of your hidden neurons...

```
for (int i = 0; i < hiddenUnit.size(); i += 1) {
```

... containing another loop that executes for all the output neurons...

```
for (int x = 0; x < outputUnit.size(); x++) {
```

... and an additional inner loop that executes again for all the hidden neurons...

```
double[] newOuts = new double[hiddenUnit.size()];
for (int t = 0; t < newOuts.length; t++) {
```

... and you execute all of that *ten thousand times*. Add on top of this O(i + h + o) [initial object creation] + O(i*h + o*h) [initial weights] + O(h*i) [calculate net inputs] + O(h*o) [calculate net outputs].

No wonder it's taking forever; your code is littered with nested loops. If you want it to go faster, factor these out - for example, combine object creation and initialization - or reduce the number of neurons. But significantly cutting the number of back propagation calls is the best way to make this run faster.